# Meteor - Can't run tasklist.exe on Windows 8.1

Tags: meteor, windows-8.1

I installed the newest version of Meteor (v 1.1.0.2) using the Windows Installer. I am using Windows 8.1. Everything seems to have installed correctly as I am able to create new meteor projects using `meteor create projectName`. When I enter the project and run `meteor`, it crashes with the following error:

```
C:\projects
λ meteor create projectName
projectName: created.

To run your new app:
  cd projectName
  meteor

C:\projects
λ cd projectName\

C:\projects\projectName
λ meteor
[[[[[ C:\projects\projectName ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.

C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: Couldn't run tasklist.exe: {"killed":false,"code":1,"signal":null}
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:120:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:236:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:360:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:612:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:712:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:670:10)
    at C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-all.js:199:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\Users\Nate\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:73:24
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:662:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:979:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

All the solutions I have found relate to not having tasklist.exe as part of the PATH which I have since added but the issue still persists. What do I need to do to get Meteor to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue in **Windows 7** and the solution was to **run the CMD as administrator**.

What is strange is that without being administrator I was able to use `tasklist.exe` from the CMD.

Comment: Thanks Pragmateek, this ended up being my solution. Had to do the same for Windows 10 as well.

Comment: @NatePerry Glad it helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Windows 8.1, there is some kind of issue with task list in OS that can be fixed with an update. Try going to Windows Update in Control Panel and install optional updates. It worked for me.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2732840

If not, there is more here:

https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues/71#issuecomment-77924368

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for the response. I installed 20+ optional updates but still had no luck after restarting. The Github issue doe snot really have a solid answer, but I will explore it more.

Comment: The Microsoft KB articles says it's for Windows 8, but when you try to download it, it only says it's for Windows 7 and Vista and Windows 2008.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue but after setting up the environment variable, It started working. add "C:\Windows\System32" in path variable.. and gonna work fine..

Comment: Thanks for the response. My PATH everything it needed. The solution was to run as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue for me was to enable Windows Instrumentation Service.

To enable the service open services.msc from the run prompt 
Change the startup type to automatic and start the service.
Once completed I was able to start the meteor app, I already had the environment paths and was running as admin, only after setting this was I am to run.