# Meteor Server Error starting up on Windows: Couldn't run tasklist.exe

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to deploy my app on my server, but whenever I navigate to localhost:3000, nothing shows up.

What's I've done

meteor create myapp

cd myapp

meteor

I'm not getting anything on my server.

Comment: What is your console output? - In the terminal window where you typed "meteor"

Comment: @MichelFloyd First line is error: couldn't run tasklist.exe : tasklist wasn't found in your system. It usually can be found at C:\windows\system32\\\ Then it just finds mongo and runs it.

Comment: I'm on MacOs so can't help you much. Your symptoms appear to be similar to those of other Win/Meteor developers. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225995/meteor-cant-run-tasklist-exe-on-windows-8-1 https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4128 and perhaps https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/AE6GYrJImAo

Comment: @MichelFloyd Thank you for the help. Have a nice day.